# Strongly-typed binding to a DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

Normally I would bind data to a `DropDownListFor` with a `SelectList`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Orders, "OrderId", "ItemName"))
```

Is there any way to do this through strongly-typed lambdas and not with property strings.  For example:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Orders, x => x.OrderId, x => x.ItemName))
```

Comment: I don't think there is. The SelectList needs to know the Id property and description property names so it can bind those properties to the control/have it in its collection. you could perhaps instead make a custom displayeditor or extension methods instead but still think you need, at some level, to tell it what the ID property and display/description property names are on the object you are trying to bind. The other solution maybe to forget using the dropdownlistfor and just have a for loop spitting out the raw html instead...maybe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create the select list itself in the controller and assign it to a property in your view model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OrdersList { get; set; }
```

The code in your controller will look like this:

```
model.OrdersList = db.Orders
                     .Select(o => new SelectListItem { Value = o.OrderId, Text = o.ItemName })
                     .ToList();
```

In the view you can use it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, Model.OrderList)
```

I personally prefer this approach since it reduces logic in your views. It also keeps your logic 'stronly-typed', no magic strings anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be an overloaded constructor to allow for this.
But there's no harm in manually specifying the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` as a string is there?

Comment: There is a maintainability issue with using strings as a mismatch will throw a runtime exception.  With strongly-typed binding this would be covered by the static compiler.

Comment: Agree with the maintainability, the setting of the DataTextField and DataValueField has been around for quite sometime now from Winforms to Asp.net etc so perhaps finding a way to do this the way you're suggesting would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

for that u can use a ViewBag for storing a data into your Drop Down Control

here is an example of it ..............

```
@Html.DropDownList("department", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.DepartmentList, new { value = @ViewBag.department, style = "width:140px", onchange = "OnDepartmentChange(this)" })
```

in controller in Index method you can write like

```
 ViewBag.Department = department;
```

Comment: ya defiantly dude can we share our Skype

Answer (score 0):

When we use strongly typed views, we can use the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` method. This helper method will need the list of departments to first populate the dropdown and then set the employee’s department id passed in model object as selected item.

```
    public ActionResult edit(int id)
{
    Employee emp = db.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.DepartmentListItems = db.Departments.Distinct().Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Text = i.DepartmentName, Value = i.DepartmentId.ToString() }).ToList();
    return View(emp);
}
```

The list items in view bag will be used to bind the dropddownlist and html helper will set the `DepartmentId` based on the `Employee` model passed to the view. View Code below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, ViewBag.DepartmentListItems as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,"Select")
```