# JQuery dropdown click function not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to jQuery, here when I click the department code dropdown list then department name want to come inside the input field as well as I used jQuery function for that. the problem is to the department name didn't come while click the dropdown. I couldn't find out my mistake in my jQuery code, if anyone find out that it will be most helpful for me. Below, I saw my necessary code only

1.Create.cshtml

```
<tr class="spaceUnder">
                        <td>
                            <label for="departmentId">DepartmentCode</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="departmentId" id="departmentId">
                                <option value="">Select...</option>
                                @foreach (var department in ViewBag.Departments)
                                {
                                    <option value="@department.ID">@department.Code</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="spaceUnder">
                        <td><label for="DepartmentName">DepName</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="DepartmentName" id="DepartmentName" data-val="true">
                        </td>
                    </tr>




     <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{                         
    $('#departmentId').change(function ()
{
    var DepId = $('#departmentId').val();                           
    var json = { DepartmentId: DepId };
    $.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",                                
    url: "/TeacherCourseAssign/GetDepartmentByDepartmentId",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    success: function
    (data) {                   
    $('#DepartmentName').val(data.Name);                            
    }
                             }
                             );
                         }
                         );
                     }
                     ); 
</script>
```

2.SubjectController.cs

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var subjects = db.Subjects.Include(s => s.Department);
            return View(subjects.ToList());
        }
```

3.TeacherCourseAssignController.cs

```
public JsonResult GetDepartmentByDepartmentId(int departmentId)
        {
            List<Department> departments = aDepartmentManager.GetAllDepartments();
            var department = departments.Find(a => a.ID == departmentId);
            return Json(department);
        }
```

4.DepartmentManager.cs

```
public List<Models.Department> GetAllDepartments()
        {
            return aDepartmentGateway.GetAllDepartment();
        }
```

5.DepartmentGateway.cs

```
 public List<Department> GetAllDepartment()
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string Query = "SELECT * FROM Departments ";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            List<Department> departments=new List<Department>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Department department = new Department()
                {
                    ID=(int)reader["ID"],
                    Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
                    Code=reader["Code"].ToString()
                };
                departments.Add(department);
            }
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();

            return departments;
        }
```

6.Subject.cs ( model )

```
public class Subject
    {
        public int SubjectID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Department")]
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("DepName")]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Do we really need to see all of your .net code? Please provide a minimal sample of your rendered html.

Comment: I would consider using the department name as the select option text.  So value is the id, and department name is the text in the pulldown.  (Include Departments in the controller Subject model so you can do Subject.Department.DepartmentName... ) Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206319/how-can-i-send-my-selectlist-value-via-asp-tags/57208076#57208076  But maybe I'm not understanding your requirements.   Why are you populating this on selection?

Comment: @LeeTaylor here I mentioned jQuery dropdown list function not working, Hence, sometime you might thought I did the mistake apart from other part codes, that is why I put other code as well, not only I didn't  put everything here , but also I put minimal reduced necessary code only.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for your contribution, This approach is not working to me.

Comment: Are there any pressing reasons not use strongly typed `DropDownListFor` since this is `mvc`? A good example is the [top answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419957/strongly-typed-binding-to-a-dropdownlistfor), which shows a very simple way to achieve this without `jquery`. Unless of course your aim is to specifically use it.

Comment: @Wubbler if you see my model class clearly, you would recognise that your approach unable to use it.. then, you could understand why i chose here jQuery as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, you made several mistake while writing the JQuery code.Try this, it might work for you.

```
@section scripts
{
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
{                         
    $("#departmentId").change(function ()
{
    var DepId = $("#departmentId").val();                           
    var json = { DepartmentId: DepId };
    $.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",                                
    url: '/TeacherCourseAssign/GetDepartmentByDepartmentId',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    success: function
    (data) {                   
    $("#DepartmentName").val(data.Name);                            
    }
                             }
                             );
                         }
                         );
                     }
                     );                                                                         
 </script>
}
```

then After try to Debugging JavaScript in your browser ,here you want to put the breakpoints appropriate place and find your solution as well.(More Details Debugging JavaScript in chrome.[LinkHere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbEx0s06VLs&t=4s))

Comment: sorry for the delay, now everything work perfectly.